# select additional rows depending on values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have statement lets say like

```
select field1,field2,field3,field4 from table1
```

and for each row where field1 is 'foo' and field2 is 'bar'
I need a second row in my result set for each of these rows.

like

```
field1  ,field2  ,field3,field4
'foo'   ,'bar'   ,...   ,...
'addrow','addrow',...   ,...
'bar'   ,'foo'   ,...   ,...
'bar'   ,'foo'   ,...   ,...
'foo'   ,'bar'   ,...   ,...
'addrow','addrow',...   ,...
'bar'   ,'foo'   ,...   ,...
'bar'   ,'foo'   ,...   ,...
```

and the additional rows must be selected from table2

Is there a way to do something like this in SQL ?

Comment: Please explain more.What do you want to print?

Comment: I just need the additional rows in my result set shown in the second block

Comment: How many? For ROW 1 you want to print ROW2 ('addrow','addrow',...   ,...) also?

Comment: I think a simple **UNION ALL** would work with a where clause as `where field1 is 'foo' and field2 is 'bar'`.

Comment: +1 for _Lalit Kumar B_ :) only question is, whether the sorting is important. This would apply a little bit more of work :)

Comment: Heh ok I thought it would be self explanatory. I need exactly 1 row for each row where field1 is 'foo' and field2 is 'bar' and I need it exactly after that row not at the end or something. I don't know how this should work with a UNION

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a number identifier, you could use:

```
select * 
  from (select id *10 as id, field1,field2 from table1
         union all
        select id *10 +1 as id, 'addrow','addrow' from table1
         where field1 = 'foo' and field2 = 'bar') 
  order by id;
```

Check [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d848/3).